# How do I know which network controller I am using on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, bluetooth, manjaro

I have bought a new laptop and I wanted to know which network controller is installed on my Manjaro Linux laptop using the command line. Is there any command to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```